# scilab - Drawing bounding box

Tags: image-processing, scilab

So in `scilab` I did a `analyzeblobs` on my image and got a feature which is called `BoundingBox` which shows the rectangle around my object.
Now when I call this bounding Box I get 4 numbers, which I suppose are related to the corners of the rectangle.
What I don't know is that what are these numbers representing? Are they the pixel Index? or what?

Basically I want to calculate the width of the rectangle of my bounding box, so I need the coordinates of those four corners, but I don't know how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I got the Answer:
the four elements are in order (x,y, width, height).
x,y are the coordinates of the top left corner
and the next two are the width and height of the rectangle.

So my second question has also been answered.